# Python difference between ring buffer and simultaneous pop-push in queue?

Tags: python, queue, buffer, structure

I'm working on an application that in a part requires to save the latest n values from a stream of data for processing the whole stream at once in intervals, overwriting the oldest value, I'm familiar with ring buffers in C which are used in low memory constrains scenarios.

Yet, In python, whats the advantage of this implementation rather than just having a queue object and at each insertion of data just performing a pop() and a push(). Are there memory vulnerabilities with this approach?

Comment: did you have a look at [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any language a ring buffer implementation offers a significant performance advantage: no data is being moved around when adding or removing elements and also the memory where those are stored is contiguous.
In python you can use `collections.deque` with `maxlen` argument, to get the same behavior and performance. Still using a plain list it is going to reasonably fast.
What do you mean by memory vulnerabilities ?